# refactoring an if/else if block within a javascript map

Tags: javascript, if-statement, refactoring, array.prototype.map

Is there a way to refactor this function "expandCols" and clean it up? I feel like the if/else if block within the map can be cleaned up but I'm brain farting.

The function below lives in a React component and is triggered when the user attempts to 'expand a column'. The props passed in to this component are the column headers and other data related to the column.

```
const expandCols = () => {
const grid = [
    { id: 1, data: 1, name: 'col1', visible: true, foreignKey: null },
    { id: 2, data: 12, name: 'test', visible: true, foreignKey: 'vis' },
    { id: 3, data: 13, name: 'test', visible: true, foreignKey: 'vis' },
    { id: 4, data: 14, name: 'test', visible: true, foreignKey: 'vis' },
    { id: 5, data: 15, name: 'not test', visible: true, foreignKey: 'not vis' },
    { id: 6, data: 16, name: 'not test', visible: true, foreignKey: 'not vis' },
    { id: 7, data: 17, name: 'random 1', visible: true, foreignKey: 'N/A' },
    { id: 8, data: 18, name: 'random 2', visible: true, foreignKey: 'N/A' },
    { id: 9, data: 19, name: 'dynamic visible col', visible: true, foreignKey: 'make me visible' },
    { id: 10, data: 20, name: 'dynamic visible col', visible: true, foreignKey: 'make me visible' },
    { id: 11, data: 21, name: 'dynamic visible col', visible: true, foreignKey: 'make me visible' },
    { id: 12, data: 22, name: 'dynamic visible col', visible: true, foreignKey: 'make me visible' },
  ];

  //value from props passed in from parent can be: 'test', 'not test', or 'dynamic visible col'
  const headerVals = props.headerVals 
  let isExpanded = true;
  grid.map((column) => {
    if (column.name === 'test' && column.foreignKey === 'yup') {
      isExpanded = !column.visible;
      return (column.visible = !column.visible);
    } else if (column.name === 'not test' && column.foreignKey === 'not yup') {
      isExpanded = !column.visible;
      return (column.visible = !column.visible);
    } else if (column.name === 'dynamic visible col' && column.foreignKey === 'make me visible') {
      isExpanded = !column.visible;
      return (column.visible = !column.visible);
    }
  });

  if (isExpanded) {
    if (headerVals === 'test') {
      // show test column in grid
      // functionality to accomplish this is used with another library
    } else if (headerVals === 'not test') {
      // show not test column in grid
      // functionality to accomplish this is used with another library
    } else if (headerVals === 'dynamic visible col') {
      // show dynamic visible col in grid
      // functionality to accomplish this is used with another library
    }
  } else {
    if (headerVals === 'test') {
      // hide test column in grid
      // functionality to accomplish this is used with another library
    } else if (headerVals === 'not test') {
      // hide not test column in grid
      // functionality to accomplish this is used with another library
    } else if (headerVals === 'dynamic visible col') {
      // hide dynamic visible col in grid
      // functionality to accomplish this is used with another library
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `grid.map()` to anything. What are the return values supposed to be used for? If you're only using it for side effects, use `forEach()` rather than `map()` and don't return things.

Comment: You could combine all the conditions into a single one that uses `||`, rather than separate `if/else if`, since they all do the same thing.

Comment: Good point about the forEach(). I just need to change the values within the grid array.

Comment: @Barmar Combining the conditions into a single one that uses `||` would look very complex, wouldn't it? I think that would be less readable than it is now.

Comment: If you format it nicely it should be readable. It avoids the implication that you're treating each set of values differently, which is more cognitive overload.

Comment: Another option is `grid.filter(column => conditions).forEach(column => { column.visible = !column.visible; isVisible = column.visible; })`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you :) I'll look at implementing some of these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
grid.forEach((column) => {
    if (
      (column.name === 'test' && column.foreignKey === 'yup') ||
      (column.name === 'not test' && column.foreignKey === 'not yup') ||
      (column.name === 'dynamic visible col' && column.foreignKey === 'make me visible')
    ) {
      isExpanded = !column.visible;
      column.visible = !column.visible;
    }
  });
```

Comment: @Thel1 Thank you so much. I actually went with something similar to that. Appreciate you taking the time to comment :)